# Password generator in SQL

Tags: sql, generator

I have a table in database. Sometimes (for example, 1 time in a month) I need to fill it with 10 rows of generated **NONREPEATABLE** codes (like password or promo).

Length - **10**

Chars - **0..9, 'A'..'Z'**

Table's columns: **id, code**

Hope for some help
Thanks

**[EDITED]**

I have found the way by using this tutorial [How to generate unique promotion...](http://www.republicof3.com/how-to-generate-unique-promotion-discount-codes-in-php/) on PHP...

Thanks everybody answered )

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? i.e. Oracle, SQL Server etc. Also, does this need to be in pure SQL or would you be happy with a solution in a programming language?

Comment: @ChrisProsser I use MySQL+PHP+iPad Application. So through php-script I would like to check the list of codes. Filling method not in the iPad app, so I would like do that myself by sql (or may be php) script

Comment: Er, given `mt_rand()` isn't considered cryptographically secure, the output of the function can be (theoretically) predicted.  [From the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) you may want to look into a different function.  Note that this may not be terribly important if your site is small/promotions not as enticing.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast((Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%10) as varchar(1)) + 
   char(ascii('a')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) +
   char(ascii('A')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) +
   left(newid(),5)
```

from yourTable
**Try this**

Comment: ...you're ignoring a huge portion of allowed values, given that you have 1 leading digit, followed by a single upper and lower case letter, then (probably) 5 more digits - for a maximum of 8 characters (not the requested 10)...  and that's the least of the problems here.  Going off of experience with other RDBMSs, `NEWID()` is likely generating sequential ids from the given table, which is going to reduce the 'randomness' of the result to practically 0.  Note that doing this in SQL is often difficult - much easier to use a HLL which has cryptographic features.